# connect python to c++

Tags: python, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am not sure how to use the variables and function of a python code (.py) in a cpp file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215827/connect-python-to-c++/) by [Fi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22677/fi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-08-13

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-08-13**:
This is kind of a big question, and this forum is specifically for ROS support. Can you describe how you want to use Python and C++ with ROS?

**Comment by [Fi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22677/fi/) on 2015-08-14**:
I have two code in ROS One written by C++ and another one with python. I want to use in ROS  c++ code the output of python code(variables, functions) as input of C++ program!

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-17**:
I think this kind of questions would be better in stackoverflow, but if you are flexible about the solution, publishing/subscribing is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, if you have two **nodes** written in different languages, you can have one publish its output to a topic, and have the other node subscribe to that topic.

Trying to call Python functions from C++ is **possible**, but it's not usually a good idea due to the complexity and the overhead involved.

If you want a more specific answer, you'll need to provide more specifics (and preferably examples) of what you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5